# React: Add onClick functionality on anchor tag

Tags: reactjs, onclick, anchor

I want add onClick event in according to anchor class like "clickevent" but problem is that anchor tag come after some event

```
<a href="javascript:void(0);" class="clickevent">test</a>
```

I Below code is working fine but i got link like above

```
<a href="javascript:void(0);" onClick={this.openDemoModal.bind(this)}> {this.props.children? this.props.children : 'Demo popup'}</a>
```

Am using react

Comment: Your question is not at all clear. Please add some code snippet.

Comment: @DiwakarSingh Can you please help me.

Comment: *anchor tag come after some event* - By this you mean that you are dynamically adding anchor tag?

Comment: @DiwakarSingh yes its appear after some event EX: i submit city name and they revert its exist or not in anchor tag. now i want to add click event on that anchor tag.

Comment: If this anchor tag is coming from any of your component then you can bind onClick inside that component.
If this is coming from any third party library then you need to check if they are expecting any onClick callback for this anchor tag. If you library is not expecting any prop then I think in react world you will not be able to do that!

Comment: @DiwakarSingh its come from GQL not from any component